# File comparison in Perl - by line or substring

Tags: perl, file, compare, line

i m trying to compare 2 text files and i got down the following perl script, but for some reason even when i use the /same/ file as a base and filter, it doesnt output anything. I m really new to Perl, so apologies if any of this sounds base.

```
my $file_base = 'CSP8216.TXT';
my $file_filter = 'CSP8216.TXT';

open my $info_filter, $file_filter or die "Die: Could not open $file_filter: $!";
while(my $line_filter = <$info_filter>)
{
    open my $info_base, $file_base or die "Die: Could not open $file_base: $!";
        while(my $line_base = <$info_base>)
        {
            if("$line_filter"=="$line_base")
            #if(substr($line_filter, 0, 11)==substr($line_base, 0, 11))
            {
                print $line_base; 
            }


        }
        close $info_bae;


}
close $info_filter;
```

Could someone point out why this doesnt seem to work?

Comment: use `eq` to compare strings: if($line_filter eq $line_base). also `use strict` to see Errors in your program

Comment: worked with eq, i editted my question. Thank you Jens!

Comment: You should not Change the question, because the question makes no sence after editing

Comment: I have added my comment as Answer. Feel free to accept and/or uvote it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would do it a little different
Obviously you probably done want to push the file into an array if they are large.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

use Data::Dumper;

my $file_base = '1.TXT';
my $file_filter = '2.TXT';

open ( FILTER, "<$file_filter" ) 
        or die "Die: Could not open $file_filter: $!";

open ( BASE, "<$file_base" )
    or die "Die: Could not open $file_base: $!";

my @filterArray = <FILTER>;
my @baseArray = <BASE>;
close BASE;
close FILTER;

unless( arrayDiff( \@filterArray , \@baseArray ) )
{
    print "Success!";
}

sub arrayDiff {
    my $array1 = shift(@_);
    my $array2 = shift(@_); 

    my %array1_hash;
    my %array2_hash;

    # Create a hash entry for each element in @array1
    for my $element ( @{$array1} ) {
       $array1_hash{$element} = @{$array1};
    }

    # Same for @array2: This time, use map instead of a loop
    map { $array2_hash{$_} = 1 } @{$array2};

    for my $entry ( @{$array2} ) {
        if ( not $array1_hash{$entry} ) {
            return 1;  #Entry in @array2 but not @array1: Differ
        }
    }
    if ( keys %array1_hash != keys %array2_hash ) {
       return 1;   #Arrays differ
    }
        else {
       return 0;   #Arrays contain the same elements
    }
}
```

perl  1156663.pl

Success!

Answer (score 2):

Use `eq` to compare strings:

`if($line_filter eq $line_base)`.

Also use `use strict` to see errors in your program